# Python wait for animation to be completed

Tags: python, blender

I have been using Blender's Python API to animate an object falling from a height. The Python program will start the animation and then pause the animation at frame 250. However, I would like the Python program to wait until this process has finished before continuing.
The snippet of code is below, where I want the final line of code to wait for the condition to be set in the pause_at_frame handler. One solution I experimented with, was to create a threading event. I would then start a thread calling `pause_at_frame` and set the threading event when the current frame was 250. The program would then wait for the threading event to be set. I could not manage to get this working without the program hanging. Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 0
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()

def pause_at_frame(scene):
    frame_current = bpy.context.scene.frame_current
    if frame_current == 250:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel()
        bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 250
        # condition here

for i in range(len(bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre)):
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.pop()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(pause_at_frame)

# Wait here for condition
```

**OTHER SOLUTION:**

The other solution to this scenario is to bake the animation first.
`bpy.ops.nla.bake(frame_start=1, frame_end=250, bake_types={'OBJECT'})` removing the need for the program above.